# PerfView: Opening GC Heap Net Mem Stats taking forever

Tags: perfview

I've got relatively small etl files (100MB taken together), but when I click on GC Heap Net Mem Stacks, and wait a long time (10 minutes +), it never comes back from 'gray state'.

Any ideas if this is 'normal' or not?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is just, yes, it takes a VERY long time:

```
Started: Opening GC Heap Net Mem (Coarse Sampling) Stacks
Produced 0.396K events
[Computing the processes involved in the trace.]
Completed: Opening GC Heap Net Mem (Coarse Sampling) Stacks   (Elapsed Time: 0.103 sec)
Started: Opening GC Heap Net Mem Stacks
Produced 3.141K events
[Computing the processes involved in the trace.]
Completed: Opening GC Heap Net Mem Stacks   (Elapsed Time: 1033.355 sec)
```